# How to install Google app engine launcher in my ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, google, google-app-engine

I have read previous posts about it, but those don't seem to be working now.
I tried

```
sudo apt-get install python-wxversion python-wxglade
```

and then

```
    svn checkout
http://google-appengine-wx-launcher.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/
google-appengine-launcher
```

But got an error

```
svn: E160013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://google-appengine-wx-launcher.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/google-appengine-wx-launcher-read-only'
svn: E160013: '/svn/trunk/google-appengine-wx-launcher-read-only' path not found
```

Please help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

Google code has been [shut down](https://code.google.com/archive/about) in 2015, so the SVN access will not work anymore and it seems that the project has not been maintained for a long time.

However, the source code is not lost: see the [google code archive page](https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-appengine-wx-launcher/source/default/source), where you can

- download the source code
- or export the project to git-hub

Comment: can you explain me every step. I dont know how to do those stuffs.

Comment: what do you mean? just click the Download link and extract the zip archive: then you have the source code available.

Comment: Actually I did that but when I try to run any app in launcher , It fails n I get this in log 
" dev_appserver.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --admin_console_server=
2016-05-17 01:45:24  IST (Process exited with code 2)
"

Comment: well, that's another problem, not related to Ubuntu - I guess you should ask on stackoverflow - python

Comment: @RISHAVKUMAR Have you found any solution for the latter problem?